# solr sunspot fulltext search based on boolean field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, full-text-search, sunspot

I have two columns in my db field1 and field2. I want to do fulltext search based on another field.

I need below scenario

```
if field2.nil?
 fulltext search with field1
else
 fulltext search with field2
end
```

model.rb

```
searchable do 

 text :field1
 text :field2

  boolean :check_fields do
   self.field2.nil? ? false : true
  end
end
```

controller.rb

```
Model.search do     
 fulltext keyword, :fields => :field1 if :check_fields

 fulltext keyword, :fields => :field2 if :check_fields
end
```

I'm not getting expected results. How can I achieve condition based fulltext search.

I even tried "any do" between this two fulltext.

Can you guys please help me in getting output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem
I could directly write my condition in model.

model.rb

```
searchable do 
 text :field1
 text :searchable_field do
  field2.nil? ? field1 : field2
 end 
end
```

controller.rb

```
Model.search do     
 fulltext keyword, :fields => :searchable_field
end
```